# How to design layout programmatically, android?

Tags: android, layout

[image: Layout design]

I need to design the above layout through java coding. 
B1 & B2-> Horizontal linear layout
B3 & B4-> Horizontal linear layout
B5 & B6-> Horizontal linear layout
B7 & B8-> Horizontal linear layout
B9,B10 & B11-> Horizontal linear layout
Parent layout is Linearlayout.

This is how I am proceeding

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainl); \\PARENT LAYOUT


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    l1.setLayoutParams(params);
    l2.setLayoutParams(params);
    l3.setLayoutParams(params);
    l5.setLayoutParams(params);
    l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    l2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    l3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    l5.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    l1.addView(btn1);
    l1.addView(btn2);
    l2.addView(btn3);
    l2.addView(btn4);
    l3.addView(btn5);
    l3.addView(btn6);
    l5.addView(btn9);
    l5.addView(btn10);
    l5.addView(btn11);
    l.addView(l1);
    l.addView(l2);
    l.addView(l3);
    l.addView(l5);


}
```

Though I am not succeeding with my output. Please help me out.

Comment: hi please specify ....that it is a dashborad or what?? in this given image... b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 are looking like in a grid view and b7 b8 b9 are in a horizontal linear layout!!! please specify what exactly you need!!

Comment: everything is in horizontal linear layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams LL_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LL_params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams btn_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0
            , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btn_params.weight=1;

    l1.setLayoutParams(LL_params);
    l2.setLayoutParams(LL_params);
    l3.setLayoutParams(LL_params);
    l4.setLayoutParams(LL_params);
    l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    l2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    l3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    l4.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    btn1.setLayoutParams(btn_params);
    btn2.setLayoutParams(btn_params);
    btn3.setLayoutParams(btn_params);
    btn4.setLayoutParams(btn_params);
    btn5.setLayoutParams(btn_params);
    btn6.setLayoutParams(btn_params);
    btn7.setLayoutParams(btn_params);
    btn8.setLayoutParams(btn_params);
    btn9.setLayoutParams(btn_params);

    l1.addView(btn1);
    l1.addView(btn2);

    l2.addView(btn3);
    l2.addView(btn4);

    l3.addView(btn5);
    l3.addView(btn6);

    l4.addView(btn7);
    l4.addView(btn8);
    l4.addView(btn9);

    l.addView(l1);
    l.addView(l2);
    l.addView(l3);
    l.addView(l4);
```